# hibernate program

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote a program in netbeans on hibernate framework to persist my data in mysql db,
Everything is going fine, the main is arising when I am using the snippet session.save(newcustomer);

session--object of Session.
newcustomer-- object of entity class.

Sample Snippet--

```
public tab_customer create(tab_customer newCustomer) {
     Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        System.out.println(transaction.isActive());

        session.save(newCustomer);

        transaction.commit();

        return newCustomer;
    }
```

Its throwing error can anyone help me please.

Comment: what error does it throws? you forgot to add stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you begin two transactions. Comment out `transaction.begin();`.